# Plot circles on axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I'm just getting to grasp with plots and tikzpictures on latex. 
I can draw lines and functions now and manipulate them how i want, but i need to plot a circle.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=-4:4, 
    samples=10, 
    color=red,
]
{2*x+1};
\addlegendentry{$2x+1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what i'm using for the line, and i need to add a circle on there.

Comment: `\addplot[only marks,mark=o,red,samples at={...}] ...` where the first `...` lists the position of your circle(s) and the second `...` is as above in your code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to graph a circle would be to graph the upper and lower portions separately.  For the circle of radius 3 centered at the origin you can use:

```
\addplot [domain=-3:3, blue] {sqrt(9-x^2)};
\addplot [domain=-3:3, blue] {-sqrt(9-x^2)};
```

[image]

### Notes:

- Need to use `axis equal=true` to ensure that the scale used on the x-axis is the same as that on the y-axis. Otherwise, the circle will look like an ellipse.
- I shifted the placement of the legend by setting `legend style`.
- You can also use parametric equations if you prefer:

  ```
    \addplot[domain=-180:180, My Style, blue] ({3*cos(x)},{3*sin(x)});
  ```

  where the domain is in degrees as that is how the pgfplots trignometric function arguments are expected.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{My Style/.style={samples=100, thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    axis equal=true,
    legend style={
        cells={anchor=west},
        legend pos=north west
    },
]

\addplot [domain=-4:4, My Style, red] {2*x+1};
\addlegendentry{$y=2x+1$}

\addplot [domain=-3:3, My Style, blue] {sqrt(9-x^2)};
\addplot [domain=-3:3, My Style, blue] {-sqrt(9-x^2)};
\addlegendentry{$x^2+y^2=9$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```